# Help finding ESC for brushless motor

Tags: brushless-motors, esc

I'm very very new to hobby electronics however I have studied a bit about basic electronics in school. I have four [EMAX 0802 Brushless Motors](https://emax-usa.com/products/emax-0802-brushless-motor-for-indoor-racing-drone-tinyhawk-s-performance-part) and I want to drive them with an Arduino Nano. I know that I need an ESC, however the motors came with a specific connector. They are also very very tiny motors and I would like my ESCs to be fairly small too.

Here is a picture of the motor:
[image]

Does anyone have some advice on the best way to control this brushless motor? I assume that I am going to have to re-solder the connector since it is designed specifically for a prebuilt drone.

Comment: That's probably correct. Unless someone here can identify the connector type and you can get a pigtail to make use of the connector. I know I've seen it before, but I can't place the name. :(

Comment: @ifconfig thanks for the response! Do you think that almost any ESC designed for a brushless motor would work with these brushless motors, as long as I re-soldered the connections?

Comment: Yes, that's likely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ESCs for these tiny motors are always built into a single board that also contains the flight controller (and often the receiver and video transmitter). I'm afraid you won't find them individually. The quadcopters that they're designed for just don't have room for separate components, and everything is so tiny that the plugs and wires would be a significant weight penalty.

That said, there's no reason that a larger ESC won't work. The smallest generally available is about 6amp, but you might find 10 or 12 amp units for the same price and size - small stuff is rare and doesn't get updated as often as the more common sizes.

FWIW, I think that's a 3 pin JST 1.25mm connector. Measure the pin spacing to check.

Comment: What about [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XM2DF4C)?

Comment: @ArjunSahlot - yes that would work