# Wiring a 4-in-1 ESC to an Arduino Uno

Tags: flight-controller, esc

I have [four brushless motors](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/help-finding-esc-for-brushless-motor) that I want to control using an Arduino Nano. I was looking at getting a 4-in-1 ESC controller [similar to this one on amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R4ZPJNY).

At this point in my project, I'm more interested in toying around with components and understanding how to control them using an Arduino rather than having a fully functional drone. I was wondering if anyone had a good resource on how to communicate with and control ESCs using an Arduino. Is this something that can easily be done?

[image]

It seems pretty straightforward how to solder the actual brushless motors to the ESC, however I was mainly wondering how this 8-wire connector can be used to control them from an Arduino. If I directly connect the M1/M2/M3/M4 wires to pins on my Arduino, are there libraries which can be used to control the motors?

Comment: Well, which one you get matters a lot here. :) There are several different protocols that may or may not be supported by any given part.

Comment: Some useful resources for the DSHOT protocol might be https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43851/dshot-implementation-on-arduino-esc-protocol and https://github.com/gueei/DShot-Arduino

Comment: Thanks again for your responses! I'm planning on getting the one linked on Amazon, which I believe supports the "DShot150/300/600/MultiShot/OneShot" protocols. Do you know how I could find out if my Arduino can also use these protocols? EDIT: Your second comment answers these questions, thank you!

Comment: Yeah, not natively. :P But as the arduino.SE post says, there are hacky ways to do it with AVR arduino and some more established methods if you venture into STM32 arduino. (like the Betaflight/Cleanflight/etc. FCs)

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this problem? I'm currently doing a project for school and would greatly benefit from this. I'm also looking to interface a 4 in 1 ESC with an Arduino for an autonomous drone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you must use dshot then try this library https://github.com/gueei/DShot-Arduino
However, for just playing around, it would be much easier to use PWM protocol and the servo library for Arduino.  Most ESC's are backwards compatible so I recommend trying using PWM first and if you must, use DSHOT.