# Using a raspberry pi 4 for motor control

Tags: esc, brushless-motors, raspberry-pi

I am fairly new to electronics and am trying to build a drone from scratch as a hobby project. I want a setup where I can control all the motors individually through the software. Through some research I found that ESCs are the way to go for BLDC motors, and I am planning on getting [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08XM2DF4C). I also came across [this post](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/wiring-a-4-in-1-esc-to-an-arduino-uno?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is almost identical to the thing that I am trying to do, except that I am using a Raspberry Pi. After multiple failed purchases due to  not knowing what would work with my setup, I am reluctant to buy this and want to know how to connect it before the purchase.

This is the diagram of the ESC:
[image: diagram]

My biggest worry is that the raspberry pi's diagram only has 2 PWM (pulse width modulation) pins (32, 33):
[image: raspberry pi pin diagram]

How would I connect these 2 to have access to the speeds of all the motors individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with RaspPi a lot. I will keep it short, 2 big problems:

1- PI is slow AF!  Way too slow to use for the drone feedback loop (runtime)

2- And where is the 5kloc+ of C lang code coming from? The software in use is very complex. We have not seen ANY new FC firmware in 10+ years (correct if wrong).  BetaFlight is the same code base from BaseFlight (2010 era) that was forked from another project.  KISS/FETTEC has been around for 10+ years as well.  No one is writing new firmware, many have tried.

Fianlly, the LINGYUN ESC should be skipped. If you actually are going to dedicate all this time in a total scratch build, at least get good parts and things that you can replace in a month or year.

The difference between Arduino's is grand, but many are fast little units and serve as the base for all flight controllers.  PI's don't have the dedicated C lang/asm potential you need. They will compile and run, but I don't think the perfomance will be any good.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by 5kloc+ C lang code. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: KLOC = thousand(s) of lines of code.  I am commenting on the workload regarding the code - size of the code base and complexity.  Most controllers are small ARM-like chips (no OS).  You need C lang (C language ) or similar (C++, Rust, compiled/micro python) to get the IO speed to make micro-adjustments for flight. As for kloc, I don't know the exact count - but betaflight is huge. https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/tree/master -- I know a few people who did use a Pi for flight, it was more like a "Pi was on board while another pcb did the actual flying: